# how to callback without printing to console ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So to make sure it updated you have to call back but how do i make it so that it doesn't show the callback if that callback has sensitive data for say.

my current callback code

```
handleChange(e) {
    var cse = this.state.Case;

    cse[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        Case: cse
    }, function () {
        console.log(this.state.Case);
    });
}
```

how would i callback without using console.log??

right so by removing the console.log part it stops it from printing to the console but now i get this warning how do i stop this warning

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: Not sure I understood the question correctly... but just remove the console.log?

Comment: then i get a warning its only a warning but i don't really want the warnings there. the warning is Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: Take out the console.log? You also shouldn't have sensitive data on the client side anyways, unless the user has permission to see it anyways... Because... it takes like 5 minutes to open up the developer tools and find the information anyways.

Comment: the callback in setState is optional. Simply remove it

Comment: i need the callback because i get errors in some of the areas where i am then using the data straight away so it would be using the old data @yBrodsky

Comment: I don't get it. Are you doing something in that callback, besides the console.log?

Comment: no but i need to modify the variable straight after and if i remove the callback i get errors where variable aren't defined because it hasn't updated the data

Comment: Why don't you show us more code to understand what you are doing. If you have to setState and then you have to do something when that setState is done, then you need the callback. The data was there in the first place, will be there afterwards. So there's no point in being paranoid about data sensitivity

Comment: @yBrodsky I am unable to show more code as this is a work project and I can only share specific parts

Comment: Andy, all I can say is that you don't need a callback if all you're doing is a console.log. If there's more you're doing there then just remove the console.log. It's that simple really.

Comment: @andywilson you get a warning, because it's empty funciton, just remove it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "callback" is just a function which executes once the original one has completed - in this case once the `state` has been updated. However, you are never *forced* to use the callback. It's not a required parameter.

See [`setState()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState(updater, [callback])

The `[]` here means the argument is *optional*.

---

So if you don't want to console.log anything, you can remove just that. If you get a warning in ESLint about an empty block statement or something, you could remove the callback altogether.

So like:

```
this.setState({
    Case: cse
});
```

Comment: if i remove the callback function i get errors so i can't do that

Comment: That can't be right. What error do you get specifically?

Comment: i get undefined error as im setting states for the first time from when they were just set in state as for example Case: ''

Comment: I understood nothing from that sentence :p